# Row Key/Partition and node location

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am learning Cassandra data storage/model. Want to know if there is tool which can show which ROW KEY or PARTITION exists on which NODE.

say i have 3 node cluster with a keyspace with RF=2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nodetool getendpoints` command for that. Example

```
nodetool getendpoints MY_KEY
```

It will show you which nodes are replica for that data.

Addition information: You can also use `nodetool ring` command to show the token distribution. It's a bit harder to understand for newbies though.

A quick explanation for tokens if you're interested: Basically each node has responsibility for one (or multiple if using vnodes) token. The token range that this node owns goes from the token itself and back until the previous node token. This token range is replicated desired number of times for nodes that owns the following tokens (going forward).

This image explains it well: [image]

Image source: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/repair-in-cassandra

Comment: Your explanation explains it well. But my confusion still exists. The above diagram is similar to single token range and for RF=2 the next two node (clock wise) will have the copies of the data. Please correct my understanding... 1. total range is -2^63 to +2^63. 2. If I build a 3 node cluster each with num_tokens = 256 then will Cassandra create a total number of token ranges = 3x256. ? 2. And these token ranges vary in length. ? 3. are these ranges allocated to the nodes in increasing order still? Guess this cannot be random or else how clockwise replica copy will work... I am very confused.

Comment: 1. Correct. The total range when using Murmur3 partittioner (default) will be -263^2 to +263^2-1.

Comment: 2. Correct, in a 3 node cluster with RF=3 you will have 3x256 token ranges. Of course each node will own all of these ranges because of the RF.

Comment: 2. The idea with using vnodes is that you distribute them randomly 
and the more vnodes you use the more even distribution you will have. There have been cases where the token distribution was unbalanced which is why a better distribution of tokens was added in Cassandra 3.0 using the allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor setting in cassandra.yaml. For more information see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__num_tokens

Comment: 3. They are randomly distributed as default (see 2). Tokens don't have to be created in order. Cassandra simply understands that it can't replicate a range to a succeeding vnode if the node holding that vnode already has another vnode that replicates the data. So Cassandra will simply skip that vnode as replica for the data and go to the next vnode. Was this clear enough or should I explain further?

Comment: It also works the same with replicating to datacenters. Say you have 2 datacenters with 3 nodes each. n1, n2, n3 is part of dc1. You have RF=1 for dc1 and RF=3 for dc2. For a fictional token range 1-10 a vnode v1 is primary replica for the data. v1 is owned by n1. We have succeeding tokens owned by v2 and v3 which are owned by n2 and n3. These vnodes will not become replicas for the data because we have already satisifed our RF for dc1. The succeeding ranges are then owned by v4, v5 and v6 which are owned by n4, n5 and n6. These will of course be replicas in order to satisfy the RF.

Comment: Hello.. it is still not clear..reading n number of docs but nothing is helping me. Say the token range us 100, 3 nodes each with 5 vnodes. Meaning 15 vnodes in total. Range of 100 will be unequally divided in 15 token ranges. Simple strategy.. RF= 2, Now a write request comes and partioner decides node 2 as the node. On what basis is the replica decided now? As the token ranges are randomly allocated to 3 nodes.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. A replica doesn't get chosen per request, a node gets chosen as replica for a token range whenever the cluster gets initialized or when it scales.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am very clear with INITIAL TOKEN setting and RF=n. But with vnode = 256. Say the cluster is with 1 node only. so it gets 256 token ranges. 1. Are these token ranges listed serially? 2. Now 2nd node is added with vnode=256.  so the entire range is again refactored into 2x256 = 512 token ranges. Some of these token ranges will be allocated to node2. say for token range x, is the replica token range decided at this stage? 3. node3 is added with vnode=256. # token ranges = 3x256. token ranges will be re-ranged & re-allocated to the 3 nodes. Replica will be decided?

Comment: You're thinking of it wrong. With vnodes you don't rearrange the tokens. For example when adding a node you simply insert the new 256 vnodes randomly into the token ring. All tokens owned by existing nodes in the cluster stay the same, however some token ranges get smaller.

Comment: Perhaps this image will help you understand: https://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/VNodesShuffled.png . The nodes are unfortunately wrong but it's the best I could find. Each node has it's own color, just don't like at the right side. Now, use your imagination to add a node to this picture, one at a time. Start with an empty cluster. Now add the yellow node. As you can see the vnodes A, V, W, X are placed randomly in the ring. Next, add the blue node with vnodes N, O, P, Q.

Comment: This is how adding nodes work in Cassandra with vnodes. Tokens for the old nodes remain the same but the token ranges changes when new vnodes (tokens) get added. These new vndoes takes over a part of another vnodes token range.

Comment: Thanks for having patience with my incompetence. Understood the diagram.

Comment: For the vnode A, which one will be the replica vnode as you stated the replica is decided at cluster initiation or reshuffle. Help appreciated

Comment: With RF=3 that would be G and O since they own the tokens after A.

Comment: But G and O are on the same node.

Comment: Like I tried saying before the nodes are incorrect, don't look at the right picture. The nodes are in color, so Node 1 is A, V, W, X.